# How to point asset files listed in sw.js to a CDN path in vite.js with vitePWA plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, vite, workbox

I just migrated to vite.js from webpack. I have issues getting sw.js to preload assets listed in the file from a cdn.

This is part of the compiled `sw.js` by Vite:

```
define(["./workbox-fgffgfg"], (function(s) {
    "use strict";
    self.addEventListener("message", (s => {
        s.data && "SKIP_WAITING" === s.data.type && self.skipWaiting()
    })), s.precacheAndRoute([{
        url: "assets/create-form-53cf1c8a.js",
        revision: null
    }, {
        url: "assets/post-9e6c5856.js",
        revision: null
    }
    ....
    ])
```

Is it possible to point these assets to `https://www.resource.fakesite/assets/create-form-53cf1c8a.js`, `https://www.resource.fakesite/assets/post-9e6c5856.js`? The `viteS3()` plugin uploads all these assets to s3 and I use cloudflare to serve these files on a subdomain. I do not have these files in `https://www.fakesite/assets` but they are accessible at `https://www.resource.fakesite/assets`.

vite.ts.config

```
    export default defineConfig(async () => {
      return {
        // I assigned a CNAME to my s3 bucket in amazon S3 using cloudflare
        base: "https://www.resource.fakesite/",
        plugins: [
          importToCDN(),
          VitePWA({
            base: "/",
            registerType: "prompt",
            manifest: {
              name: "xxx",
              short_name: "xxx",
              icons: xxx,
              display: "standalone",
              start_url: `xxx`,
              orientation: "portrait",
            },
          }),
          react({
            babel: {
              parserOpts: {
                plugins: ["decorators-legacy", "classProperties"],
              },
            },
            include: "**/*.{jsx,tsx}",
          }),
          viteS3(),
        ],
      };
    });
```

I've tried the `base` setting in VitePWA but that would just point `manifest.webmanifest`, `registerSW.js` to the cloudflare route which would make it impossible to install the service worker due to same-origin issues.

```
VitePWA({ base: "/",})
```

compiled index.html would become:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="https://resource.fakesite/manifest.webmanifest"><script id="vite-plugin-pwa:register-sw" src="https://resource.fakesite/registerSW.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the `modifyURLPrefix` option to prefix the cdn address to the asset urls listed in `sw.js`. Rebuild it and now the files in sw.js have correct url addresses.

```
  VitePWA({
    base: "/",
    registerType: "prompt",
    manifest: {},
    workbox: {
      modifyURLPrefix: {
        "": `https://resource.faksite.com/`
      },
      globPatterns: ["**/*.{js,css}"],
      navigateFallback: null,
    },
  }),
```